# Adding text to arrows in Tree

Tags: tikz-trees, trees, tikz-qtree

I am currently working on the following chart:
[image: Flow chart]

What I am trying to do is to include 'Yes'and 'No' in their respective arrows rather than in its own box.

This I what I have achieved so far:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=1.75in,sibling distance=.25in,scale=0.75]
\tikzset{edge from parent/.style= 
    {thick, draw,},every tree node/.style={draw,minimum width=1.5in,text width=1.5in, align=center},grow'=right}
\Tree 
[. {Does ordre matter} 
[.{Yes}
[.{\mbox{Repetition?}} ]
]
[.{No}
]
] 
]

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How can I achieve the 'Yes' or 'No' text been written in the arrows?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Hello @hpekristiansen, I have just done that. Thanks for raising that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the `\edge` command that is explained in [section 5 of the tikz-qtree manual](https://texdoc.org/serve/tikz-qtree/0).

Though, I'm not sure if `tikz-qtree` is the best option right now.
The `forest` package can draw tree diagrams very well and TikZ itself has the both the `graphs` as well as the `graphdrawing` library.

### Code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  level distance=1.75in,
  sibling distance=.5in,
  auto,
  scale=0.75,
  edge from parent/.style={thick, draw},
  every tree node/.style={
    draw,text width=1.5in, align=center,font=\strut},
  grow'=right
]
\Tree
[.{Does order matter}
  \edge node    {Yes}; [.Repetition ]
  \edge node['] {No};  [.\dots{} ]
]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to include arrows at the end of the line? In the documentation that you mention does not seem to include it. Thank you.

Comment: Add `->` or any other arrow specification to the `edge from parent` style.

Comment: Thank you  @Qrrbrbirlbel